# How to add my LinkedList to Defaultcomboboxmodel, and display it in a JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I created a  class with eclipse and jigloo and in this class there is a `LinkedList` that contains `Cars`. When i try to make this list display in the `JList` on my Gui, i  always get errors.
How can i do this please.I will be glad if someone can put me through.

Comment: If only we saw your code, and the complete error message, we could help you fix the issue.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If you decide to post code please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: JList does not take a `List` in its constructor. However, it does take `Vector`

Comment: Hold on a second..let me gaze into my crystal ball..

Comment: Please read [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing several helpful comments:

- The simple approach is to construct the `DefaultComboBoxModel` using a `Vector` constructed from the `List`:

  ```
  List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
  list.add("Test");
  Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>(list);
  DefaultComboBoxModel dcm = new DefaultComboBoxModel(vector);
  JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(dcm);
  ```
- Alternatively, extend `AbstractListModel` and implement `ComboBoxModel`.

See also [*How to Use Lists*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).